# greater reconstruction error with Autoencoder while training on Google Colab

Tags: autoencoder

I am training an Autoencoder on Google Colab using the GPU. Every time I run the training afresh, the predicted result seems to have a greater image reconstruction error than the last time. The weights are initialised randomly, however this should not have a very significant impact on the predictions. And each new training is done as the training is done the first time. I want to know why does this happen. Is this problem related to the complexity of the model or a cache related problem?

Comment: Elaborate your problem and share the code of your model.

Comment: I am trying to produce the results from the following git repo (https://github.com/WeizmannVision/ssfmri2im) on a custom dataset. After I train the model once and save the result. I remove the weight files and unmount and then mount the drive once again and train the model again (Just to check the noise in the model) and the predicted reconstructed image has greater error than the previous training of the model